# How to get Meteor Package information within the app?

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to get a list of all available packages and their configuration within a running MeteorJS app.

I don't mean the CLI command `meteor list` but something that could let me check if certain packages are available or not and change the programs behaviour accordingly.

Comment: I've no idea why someone down voted this perfectly sensible question. I've added an up vote to cancel it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Using code from the [meteorhacks SSR package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr) as an example, you can [see](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr/blob/master/lib/api.js) that it does this to check for the existence of the Jade package:

```
if(Package['mquandalle:jade-compiler']) {
  Compilers.jade = Package['mquandalle:jade-compiler'].JadeCompiler;
}
```

The caveat is that the other package has to be added first.